# Sending variable from one JS file to another JS file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have ABC.jsp file with the corresponding ABC.js file. I also have XYZ.jsp file with the corresponding XYZ.js file.
I have a variable VAR in ABC.js file. I want to send that variable by Post method to the XYZ.js file so that I can use the variable VAR in XYZ.js for some computations . These computations will help me in changing the content of XYZ.jsp file.

I want to send the variable VAR in a javascript function (obviously in ABC.js file) which gets called when a button on ABC.jsp is clicked.

So, can anyone please help me in sending the variable from ABC.js to XYZ.js by post method. And also how to retrieve the variable in XYZ.js file.

I'm novice in this area. Any help will be much helpful for me.

Comment: why do you want to send this variable by POST method ?

Answer (score 0):

make your ABC.js script with the variable to pass it by GET method to XYZ.jsp page

```
XYZ.jsp?variable=1234
```

than, when XYZ.jsp gets rendered with 'variable' parameter passed, it will render this variable somewhere... even as a global JavaScript variable.

// this is going to be rendered in JSP where you just assign the value from the parameter passed to the JSP page

```
<script>
    myVariable="1234";   // in JPS   myVariable=\"${param.variable}\";
</script>
```

read myVariable from you ABC.js script

Comment: I cannot send the data by GET method. The URL will change. And I'm not allowed to change the URL.

Comment: so probably your only alternatives is 1. to pass the variable to ABC.JSP, store it in a session on a server side and read it from XYZ.JSP or 2. save it to a cookie and read a cookie from XYZ.js

Comment: Is it not possible by POST method?

Comment: You can pass your parameters by POST from ABC to XYZ, but you will not get redirect from ABC page with the form to a XYZ page with your results.You can do a Javascript redirect after the form gets submitted, but if so you have to store somewhere those parameters you passed, preferably in a http session